What do I do when the multivariate skewness and kutosis of my data are really large when running a CFA?
I am trying to run a CFA on a 25-item scale to test the fit for a 2 dimension model, but I just checked the kurtosis and skewness of the data and they are both quite large. I am not sure if there's something wrong with my code. If not, how do I fix it so it doesn't affect my CFA?
subdat <- subset(dat,
                 select = hss_1:hss_25)
names(subdat)
subdat[subdat==999] <- NA
df=drop_na(subdat)
mardiaSkew(df, use = "everything")
mardiaKurtosis(df, use = "everything")


this is what I got (pretty sure 1710 is skewness and 3668 is kurtosis?):
#> mardiaSkew(df, use = "everything")
   b1d    chi     df      p 
  1710 133356   2925      0 
#> mardiaKurtosis(df, use = "everything")
   b2d    z    p 
  3668  881    0 


mardiaKurtosis? mardiaSkew? Try building a small dataset to test and present results. If your unnamed, obscure package is well written it should have examples.
